# Why we need var object in AngularJS to post it to server(REST)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http

I try to post object to server. I try like this and it work:

```
$scope.add = function(pregled) {

            var pregled2 = pregled;
            pregled2.vreme= $scope.parseDate(pregled2.vreme);

            var pac = $routeParams.entry2;
            $http.post(
                    'http://localhost:8080/mavenproject2/fizijatar/875/pregled2/'
                            + pac + '/', pregled2).then(function(response) {
                $scope.odgovor = "Pregled uspesno dodat";
            }, function(response) {
                $scope.odgovor = "Pregled nije dodat,provarite unos forme";
            });
```

But when i try to post `param` from function it wont work:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/mavenproject2/fizijatar/875/pregled2/'
                            + pac + '/', pregled)
```

I don't understand how it works? Why i can put in http post object from function?

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: Maybe because in the first option your parsing the date in some other other form but in the second your not? `pregled2.vreme= $scope.parseDate(pregled2.vreme);` However in the second you send `pregled` not `pregled2`, with an un-formatted date i presume.. Maybe your server is rejecting it as the date isn't formatted correctly?

Comment: when i try parse data in pregled and send pregled also don t work.

Comment: There's no way to know what's happening without knowing what data are present in those variables. You'll also need to be more precise when you say "it wont[sic] work" ("won't" is the word you're looking for; also I is capitalized when speaking about yourself). Please read how to create a [mcve].